# tidyr spread function generates sparse matrix when compact vector expected

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm learning dplyr, having come from plyr, and I want to generate (per group) columns (per interaction) from the output of xtabs.

Short summary: I'm getting

```
A    B
1    NA
NA   2
```

when I wanted

```
A    B
1    2
```

---

xtabs data looks like this:

```
> xtabs(data=data.frame(P=c(F,T,F,T,F),A=c(F,F,T,T,T)))
       A
P       FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     1    2
  TRUE      1    1
```

now `do(` wants it's data in data frames, like this:

```
> xtabs(data=data.frame(P=c(F,T,F,T,F),A=c(F,F,T,T,T))) %>% as.data.frame
      P     A Freq
1 FALSE FALSE    1
2  TRUE FALSE    1
3 FALSE  TRUE    2
4  TRUE  TRUE    1
```

Now I want a single row output with columns being the interaction of levels.  Here's what I'm looking for:

```
FALSE_FALSE TRUE_TRUE FALSE_TRUE TRUE_FALSE
          1         1          2          1
```

But instead I get

```
> xtabs(data=data.frame(P=c(F,T,F,T,F),A=c(F,F,T,T,T))) %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    unite(S,A,P) %>% 
    spread(S,Freq)
  FALSE_FALSE FALSE_TRUE TRUE_FALSE TRUE_TRUE
1           1         NA         NA        NA
2          NA          1         NA        NA
3          NA         NA          2        NA
4          NA         NA         NA         1
```

I'm clearly misunderstanding something here.  I'm looking for the equivalent of reshape2's code here (using magrittr pipes for consistency):

```
> xtabs(data=data.frame(P=c(F,T,F,T,F),A=c(F,F,T,T,T))) %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% # can be omitted. (safely??)
    melt %>% 
    mutate(S=interaction(P,A),value=value) %>% 
    dcast(NA~S)
Using P, A as id variables
  NA FALSE.FALSE TRUE.FALSE FALSE.TRUE TRUE.TRUE
1 NA           1          1          2         1
```

(note NA is used here because I don't have a grouping variable in this simplified example)

---

Update - interestingly, adding a single grouping column seems to fix this - why does it synthesise (presumably from row_name) a grouping column without me telling it?

```
> xtabs(data=data.frame(h="foo",P=c(F,T,F,T,F),A=c(F,F,T,T,T))) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  unite(S,A,P) %>% 
  spread(S,Freq)
    h FALSE_FALSE FALSE_TRUE TRUE_FALSE TRUE_TRUE
1 foo           1          1          2         1
```

This seems like a partial solution.

Comment: [**This**](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/41) seems like the same issue.

Comment: @Henrik: indeed it does.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25960394/937932) is the same issue in reverse, with an explanatory comment by Hadley.  As you discovered in your update, both outputs make sense in the right context.  When the context is only implicit, `spread()` has to guess.

Comment: @nacnudus: Thanks for your helpful pointer.  I disagree in this case - I didn't discover that the expanded case makes sense - just that it existed.  Where there are NO arguments/columns from which to guess, My expectation is that it will assume that there is a single global identity.  Can you explain why this might not be true?

Comment: OK, I killed my rebuttal comment, too :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is that `spread` doesn't aggregate the data.

Hence, if you hadn't already used `xtabs` to aggregate first, you would be doing this:

```
a <- data.frame(P=c(F,T,F,T,F),A=c(F,F,T,T,T), Freq = 1) %>% 
    unite(S,A,P)
a
##             S Freq
## 1 FALSE_FALSE    1
## 2  FALSE_TRUE    1
## 3  TRUE_FALSE    1
## 4   TRUE_TRUE    1
## 5  TRUE_FALSE    1

a %>% spread(S, Freq)
##   FALSE_FALSE FALSE_TRUE TRUE_FALSE TRUE_TRUE
## 1           1         NA         NA        NA
## 2          NA          1         NA        NA
## 3          NA         NA          1        NA
## 4          NA         NA         NA         1
## 5          NA         NA          1        NA
```

Which wouldn't make sense any other way (without aggregation).

This is predictable based on the help file for the `fill` parameter:

> If there isn't a value for every combination of the other variables
>   and the key column, this value will be substituted.

In your case, there aren't any other variables to combine with the key column.  Had there been, then...

```
b <- data.frame(P=c(F,T,F,T,F),A=c(F,F,T,T,T), Freq = 1
                                , h = rep(c("foo", "bar"), length.out = 5)) %>% 
    unite(S,A,P)
b
##             S Freq   h
## 1 FALSE_FALSE    1 foo
## 2  FALSE_TRUE    1 bar
## 3  TRUE_FALSE    1 foo
## 4   TRUE_TRUE    1 bar
## 5  TRUE_FALSE    1 foo

> b %>% spread(S, Freq)
## Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (3, 5)
```

...it would fail, because it can't aggregate rows 3 and 5 (because it isn't designed to).

The `tidyr`/`dplyr` way to do it would be `group_by` and `summarize` instead of `xtabs`, because `summarize` preserves the grouping column, hence `spread` can tell which observations belong in the same row:

```
b %>%   group_by(h, S) %>%
    summarize(Freq = sum(Freq))
## Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
## Groups: h
## 
##     h           S Freq
## 1 bar  FALSE_TRUE    1
## 2 bar   TRUE_TRUE    1
## 3 foo FALSE_FALSE    1
## 4 foo  TRUE_FALSE    2

b %>%   group_by(h, S) %>%
    summarize(Freq = sum(Freq)) %>%
    spread(S, Freq)
## Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
## 
##     h FALSE_FALSE FALSE_TRUE TRUE_FALSE TRUE_TRUE
## 1 bar          NA          1         NA         1
## 2 foo           1         NA          2        NA
```

Comment: But when used in combination with dplyr groups when grouping the maximal identity set we have an implied aggregation: which iirc does not in fact operate correctly.

Comment: What is a maximal identity set?  I don't think there's any alternative to supplying a dummy grouping variable.  You can do it in the original data frame, or you could do `group_by(1)` before `spread` and then `select(-`1`)` afterwards.

Comment: I mean once all variables other than key and value have been consumed as 'enumerators' in group_by operations.  Thanks anyway

Comment: @nacnudus I just wanted to say your comment of `group_by(1)` really helped me.