# Why am I getting "repeat" rows with NAs using tidyr's spread function?

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to go from a dataframe with the following structure:

```
Date    State    Price.Name    Cost.Name   Price    Cost
Jan       AZ    firm1.price   firm1.cost    100       50
Jan       AZ    firm2.price   firm2.cost    200      100
```

to a dataframe that looks like:

```
Date    State    firm1.price    firm2.price    firm1.cost    firm2.cost
Jan        AZ            100            200            50          100
```

I have tried using spread from tidyr:

```
data=spread(data,Price.Name, Price)
data=spread(data,Cost.Name, Cost)
```

But this gives me the following dataframe:

```
Date    State    firm1.price    firm2.price    firm1.cost    firm2.cost
Jan        AZ            100            NA            50            NA
Jan        AZ             NA           200            NA           100
```

I have found another thread addressing the same issue here: [tidyr spread function generates sparse matrix when compact vector expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501577/tidyr-spread-function-generates-sparse-matrix-when-compact-vector-expected/34998493#34998493), but I couldn't determine if  a solution was reached. Someone suggested grouping by a dummy variable before using `spread`, but I have tried this to no avail.

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation, 4 years later. How has a satisfactory solution not been reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do price and cost separately and then merge (join) them (or `cbind` them, depending on the specifics of your data):

```
x <- read.table(text = "Date    State    Price.Name    Cost.Name   Price    Cost
+ Jan       AZ    firm1.price   firm1.cost    100       50
+                 Jan       AZ    firm2.price   firm2.cost    200      100",header = TRUE,sep = "")
> x %>% select(-Cost,-Cost.Name) %>% spread(Price.Name,Price)
  Date State firm1.price firm2.price
1  Jan    AZ         100         200
> x %>% select(-Price,-Price.Name) %>% spread(Cost.Name,Cost)
  Date State firm1.cost firm2.cost
1  Jan    AZ         50        100
```

Comment: this is what I ended up doing. I would have liked to do it all at once because my actual data has three "value" columns (price, cost, and margin), so the "spread then merge" method was a little messier. But this worked, so thank you!