# Spread two rows to one with tidyr

Tags: r, transpose, tidyr

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501577/tidyr-spread-function-generates-sparse-matrix-when-compact-vector-expected), [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/41) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960394/spread-with-data-frame-tibble-with-duplicate-identifiers) but still don't know how to solve the following problem within the `tidyr::spread()` function.

Here's my example data frame:

```
libary(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Jaar = c(2014L, 2018L), Gemeente = c("Stichtse Vecht", 
"Stichtse Vecht"), GMcode = c("GM1904", "GM1904"), Partij = c("VVD", 
"VVD"), Aantal_stemmen = c(4347L, 0L)), .Names = c("Jaar", "Gemeente", 
"GMcode", "Partij", "Aantal_stemmen"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
   Jaar Gemeente       GMcode Partij Aantal_stemmen
  <int> <chr>          <chr>  <chr>           <int>
1  2014 Stichtse Vecht GM1904 VVD              4347
2  2018 Stichtse Vecht GM1904 VVD                 0
```

When I run the following code I don't get the desired one row but two with NA's:

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>% # Without this in my original dataframe I'll get an error: Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows 
  spread(Jaar, Aantal_stemmen)
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 5,938 x 6
   rowid Gemeente       GMcode Partij   `2014` `2018`
   <int> <chr>          <chr>  <chr>     <int>  <int>
 1     1 Stichtse Vecht GM1904 VVD        4347     NA
 2     2 Stichtse Vecht GM1904 VVD          NA      0
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not exactly sure what you want as you didn't provide the wanted output. I hope the following is of help to you.

The call to `rowid_to_column` generates a column with 2 rows. That is what it is intended to do. Dropping it solves your problem:

```
df %>%
  # rowid_to_column() %>%
  spread(Jaar, Aantal_stemmen)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Gemeente       GMcode Partij `2014` `2018`
  <chr>          <chr>  <chr>   <int>  <int>
1 Stichtse Vecht GM1904 VVD      4347      0
```

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: Ah yes but without it my original dataset produces this error: `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows`

Comment: @Tdebeus Then please provide a dataset which exhibits this unwanted behavior. I worked with the dataset you gave .....

Comment: You're right, Thanks for your answer! I'll just delete the duplicate data. think that's a better approach. Thanks though!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help.