# tidyr::pop_quiz: is there a faster/ more transparent way to reshape the anscombe dataset?

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to get good with `tidyr`.  Is there a better way to prep the `anscombe` dataset for plotting with `ggplot2`? Specifically, I don't love having to add data (`obs_num`).  How would you do this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(datasets)

anscombe %>%
  mutate(obs_num = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -obs_num) %>%
  separate(variable, c("variable", "set"), 1) %>%
  spread(variable, value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~set)
```

Comment: I wonder how many people checked to see if `pop_quiz` is really a function in *tidyr*.  I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add the extra column in order to uniquely identify each observation in the call to `spread`. Hadley discusses this in a comment on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960394/unexpected-behavior-with-tidyr). Another approach would be to separately stack the `x` and `y` columns, as in the code below, but I don't see why that would be any better than your version. In fact, it could be worse if there are cases where the `x` and `y` values end up out of correspondence:

```
bind_cols(anscombe %>% select(matches("x")) %>% gather(set, "x"),
          anscombe %>% select(matches("y")) %>% gather(key, "y")) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  mutate(set = gsub("x", "Set: ", set))
```

Another option would be to use base `reshape`, which is more succinct:

```
anscombe %>% 
  reshape(varying=1:8, direction="long", sep="", timevar="set")
```

Comment: `reshape` is mysterious and powerful! fantastic one line solution, and I'm not convinced that the tidyverse solution is any less opaque in this case.

Comment: Yes, I find base `reshape` mysterious as well. It would be nice if `tidyr` could similarly deal with multiple pairs of corresponding columns.