# Can spread() in tidyr spread across multiple value?

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I am using the `iris` data set, first, I did some manipulation with that data set and make it into the following form

```
D1 = iris[,c(1,2,5)]
D2 = iris[,c(3,4,5)]
colnames(D1)[1:2] = c('Length','Width')
colnames(D2)[1:2] = c('Length','Width')
D1 = D1 %>% mutate(Part = 'Sepal')
D2 = D2 %>% mutate(Part = 'Petal')
D = rbind(D2,D1)
```

which looks like

```
Species  Part Length Width
1  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
2  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
3  setosa Petal    1.3   0.2
4  setosa Petal    1.5   0.2
5  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
6  setosa Petal    1.7   0.4
```

I want to use the `spread()` function in the `tidyr` to make the data set look like the following format eventually

```
Measure Part setosa versicolor virginica
Length  Petal 1.4     4.7        6.0
```

What I did is the following:

```
D4 = D %>% gather(Measure,value,3:4)
```

which gives

```
Species  Part Measure value
1  setosa Petal  Length   1.4
2  setosa Petal  Length   1.4
3  setosa Petal  Length   1.3
4  setosa Petal  Length   1.5
5  setosa Petal  Length   1.4
6  setosa Petal  Length   1.7
```

I've tried to add a row number to 'D4', since I found that sometimes, the `spread()` function will result into some error as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960394/unexpected-behavior-with-tidyr).
I don't know if there is a neat way to use `spread()` to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1):

We need to create a sequence variable by group and then `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
D %>% 
   gather(Measure, value, Length, Width) %>% 
   group_by(Species, Part, Measure) %>%
   mutate(i1 = row_number()) %>% 
   spread(Species, value) %>%
   select(-i1)
#    Part Measure setosa versicolor virginica
#*  <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1  Petal  Length    1.4        4.7       6.0
#2  Petal  Length    1.4        4.5       5.1
#3  Petal  Length    1.3        4.9       5.9
#4  Petal  Length    1.5        4.0       5.6
#5  Petal  Length    1.4        4.6       5.8
#6  Petal  Length    1.7        4.5       6.6
#7  Petal  Length    1.4        4.7       4.5
#8  Petal  Length    1.5        3.3       6.3
#9  Petal  Length    1.4        4.6       5.8
#10 Petal  Length    1.5        3.9       6.1
# ... with 190 more rows
```